# How do I include unicode strings in Python doctests?

Tags: python, unicode, doctest

I am working on some code that has to manipulate unicode strings. I am trying to write doctests for it, but am having trouble. The following is a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def mylen(word):
  """
  >>> mylen(u"áéíóú")
  5
  """
  return len(word)

print mylen(u"áéíóú")
```

First we run the code to see the expected output of `print mylen(u"áéíóú")`.

```
$ python mylen.py
5
```

Next, we run doctest on it to see the problem.

```
$ python -m
5
**********************************************************************
File "mylen.py", line 4, in mylen.mylen
Failed example:
    mylen(u"áéíóú")
Expected:
    5
Got:
    10
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in mylen.mylen
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

How then can I test that `mylen(u"áéíóú")` evaluates to 5?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want unicode strings, you have to use unicode docstrings! Mind the `u`!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def mylen(word):
  u"""        <----- SEE 'u' HERE
  >>> mylen(u"áéíóú")
  5
  """
  return len(word)

print mylen(u"áéíóú")
```

This will work -- as long as the tests pass. For Python 2.x you need yet another hack to make verbose doctest mode work or get correct tracebacks when tests fail:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

NB! Only ever use setdefaultencoding for debug purposes. I'd accept it for doctest use, but not anywhere in your production code.

Comment: Thanks! This approach won't work with any package that auto-discovers tests on Python 2.x though.

Answer (score 6):

Python 2.6.6 doesn't understand unicode output very well, but this can be fixed using:

- already described hack with `sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")`
- unicode docstring (already mentioned above too, thanks a lot)
- AND `print` statement.

In my case this docstring tells that test is broken:

```
def beatiful_units(*units):
    u'''Returns nice string like 'erg/(cm² sec)'.

    >>> beatiful_units(('erg', 1), ('cm', -2), ('sec', -1))
    u'erg/(cm² sec)'
    '''
```

with "error" message

```
Failed example:
    beatiful_units(('erg', 1), ('cm', -2), ('sec', -1))
Expected:
    u'erg/(cm² sec)'
Got:
    u'erg/(cm\xb2 sec)'
```

Using `print` we can fix that:

```
def beatiful_units(*units):
    u'''Returns nice string like 'erg/(cm² sec)'.

    >>> print beatiful_units(('erg', 1), ('cm', -2), ('sec', -1))
    erg/(cm² sec)
    '''
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a known and as yet unresolved issue in Python.  See open issues [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue2811) and [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue1293741).

Not surprisingly, it can be modified to work OK in Python 3 since all strings are Unicode there:

```
def mylen(word):
  """
  >>> mylen("áéíóú")
  5
  """
  return len(word)

print(mylen("áéíóú"))
```

Comment: Fair enough, this is probably the better general solution. However, in my case I am still constrained to Python 2.x due to dependencies on matplotlib and numpy.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to escape the unicode characters, like u'\xe1\xe9\xed\xf3\xfa'. Wasn't as easy to read though, but my tests only had a few non-ASCII characters so in those cases I put  the description to the side as a comment, like "# n with tilde".

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this approach breaks 'make doctest' with sphinx. It ends up with a 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position ...: invalid data.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I'm using it for my own doctests. Sorry, but I don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you need to ensure your docstrings are Unicode.

If you can switch to Python 3, then it would work automatically there, as *both* the source encoding is already utf-8 and the default string type is Unicode.

To achieve the same in Python 2, you need to keep the `coding: utf-8` next to which you can either prefix all docstrings with `u`, or simply add

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```